# How to replace all <br /> with \r\n using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/KPEGU/) to save a table as CSV (I have altered it a bit to include headers and exclude hidden rows). Somewhere line breaks within table cells are lost but I want to retain them as \r\n. There are plenty of similar questions online but I still find jQuery a bit mysterious and somehow I haven't been able to find a solution to this hopefully simple problem.

```
function exportTableToCSV($table, delimiter) {

    var $rows = $table.find('tr:visible');

    // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard
    // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents
    var tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
    tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character

    // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
    colDelim = '"' + delimiter + '"',
    rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

    // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
    csv = '"' + $rows.map(function (i, row) {
        var $row = $(row),
        $cols = $row.find('td, th');

        return $cols.map(function (j, col) {
            var $col = $(col),
            text = $col.text();

            return text.replace(/"/g, '""'); // escape double quotes

        }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

    }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
    .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
    .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"',

    // Data URI
    csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);
    return csvData;
}
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't have any string-handling functions like this. You should just use the normal Javascript `String.prototype.replace()` method.

Comment: BTW, `text.replace('"', '""')` will only replace the first quote, not all of them. You have to use a regular expression with the `g` modifier to perform more than one replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where the `br` elements are getting stripped:

```
var $col = $(col),
    text = $col.text();
```

One solution would be to replace them with a marker, then replace the marker with `\r\n`:

```
var $col, text;
      
$col = $(col).clone();
$col.find("br").replaceWith("<div>{{MARKER}}</div>");
text = $col.text().replace(/{{MARKER}}/g, "\r\n");
```

That

- Clones the element so we can change it without changing the document
- Finds all `br` elements within it
- Replaces each of them with a `div` with `{{MARKER}}` inside it
- Gets the text, which will have `{{MARKER}}` in it where the `br`s used to be
- Replaces `{{MARKER}}` with `\r\n`

```js
function exportTableToCSV($table, delimiter) {

    var $rows = $table.find('tr:visible');

    // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard
    // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents
    var tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
    tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character

    // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
    colDelim = '"' + delimiter + '"',
    rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

    // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
    csv = '"' + $rows.map(function (i, row) {
        var $row = $(row),
        $cols = $row.find('td, th');

        return $cols.map(function (j, col) {
            var $col, text;
          
            $col = $(col).clone();
            $col.find("br").replaceWith("<div>{{MARKER}}</div>");
            text = $col.text().replace(/{{MARKER}}/g, "\r\n");

            return text.replace(/"/g, '""'); // escape double quotes

        }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

    }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
    .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
    .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"',

    // Data URI
    csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);
    return csvData;
}

console.log(exportTableToCSV($("table"), ","));
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Testing</td>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two and<br>three</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @TomasoAlbinoni: Ah, I didn't realize you didn't have the `<br>` -- I've updated the answer.